# Unable to start redis

Tags: nginx, redis, centos

I get the following error in Redis 2.8:

```
FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR
redis-server[31954]: Reading the configuration file, at line 103
redis-server[31954]: 'logfile /var/log/redis/redis.log'
redis-server[31954]: Can't open the log file: Permission denied
systemd[1]: redis.service: main process exited, code=exited,      status=1/FAILURE
redis-shutdown[31956]: Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379:   Connection refused
systemd[1]: redis.service: con`enter code here`trol process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: Unit redis.service entered failed state.
systemd[1]: redis.service failed.
```

What is causing this?

Comment: What user are you running Redis as? Is the configuration file accessible by that user?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the line 103 from your Redis configuration file. You should find the logfile configuration in that line. Then, make sure the the user running the redis process/service has the appropriate permissions (read and write/modify) on that file/folder.